# access joomla session in php - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, joomla

I need to check if the user is logged in or not in CodeIgniter.

The login is happening in Joomla site.

I tried the following to initialize joomla .

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );

require_once ("../includes/defines.php");
require_once ("../includes/framework.php");

$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication("site");
$mainframe->initialise();

$session =& JFactory::getSession();
$user = $session->get( 'user' );
```

But I got this message:

> No configuration file found and no installation code available.
>   Exiting...

Joomla is installed on root and codeigniter on root/advanced

I am calling the code in controller.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

Now I am getting this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: BM
>
> Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 364

**Edit**

My Controller look like this

```
function is_logged()
    {

                define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
            define( 'JPATH_BASE', '../');
            define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
        require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
        //require_once ("../libraries/joomla/user/authentication.php");
        $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication("site");
        $mainframe->initialise();

        $session =& JFactory::getSession();
        $user = $session->get( 'user' );



    }
```

**Directory Structure**

```
--Public_html
  --Joomla Istallation files
  --Advanced [This is a folder ,i installed codeignitor on this folder]
```

So the path to joomla is `site.com/` and path to Codeignitor is `site.com/advanced`

**More about the Error**

Line 364 on Codeignitor Core says that :

```
// Mark a benchmark end point
    $BM->mark('controller_execution_time_( '.$class.' / '.$method.' )_end');
```

and i can see the following on the starting of CI core

```
    $BM =& load_class('Benchmark', 'core');
    $BM->mark('total_execution_time_start');
    $BM->mark('loading_time:_base_classes_start');
```

Comment: see this thread, it might help: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/183808/#879291

Comment: @AlphaMale `core/CodeIgniter.php` ...it happens when i include the joomla's `framework.php` file...

Comment: can you please show your code.

Comment: @AlphaMale there is no much code to show ..just one controller..i think that there are some problems in joomla with codeignitor ..

Comment: No just tell me where is that BM variable??

Comment: Can you post your application structure? Where is Joomla relative to Codeiginter?

Comment: @AlphaMale I updated my question with added details.

Comment: @BenSwinburne Described the application structure on the updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know its an old post but you need to make sure JPATH_BASE points to the directory where your configuration.php file is. I would use the absolute path rather than a relative path.